# Query time join using lucene + hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Using hibernate+jpa+lucene+spring boot.

So I am trying to do query time join - searching parent by child properties. And as in documentation I tried:

```
JoinUtil.createJoinQuery("participantId", false, "experimentId", qq, indexSearcher, ScoreMode.None);
```

And got error:

```
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'participantId' (expected one of [BINARY, SORTED]). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.`
```

(participantId is Long) I am not sure how to fix it. I tried using Bridges, etc. (inspirated by Google searche) but no success - still this error.

1. I would like to use `UninvertingReader` - but did not find how to instatiate one.
2. Same is for `docvalues` - do not know how to use it here.
3. I feel like problem may be with `IndexSearcher` I use, cause I get it in kinda weird way:
   new `IndexSearcher(Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager).getSearchFactory().getIndexReaderAccessor().open(Participant.class))`

Help me please )

UPDATE.
Currently solved by adding annotations:

```
@SortField
@FieldBridge(impl = LongBridge.class)
```

to join fields... Not clear why this is required - without @FieldBridge annotations no error, but no search results as well.